# how to replicate this move in edit mode from youtube video

Tags: edit-mode, sculpting

I am following this video in constructing an Easter Island figure but at 6min 15secs I struggle to scale the lips in Z as he has shown. I selected just the front faces and side vertices and then scaled with S+Z

What have I missed?

https://youtu.be/IV6de9CyuXs?t=375

[image]

Comment: at 6:15 it looks like he just extrudes the faces, but you've already done it. 30 seconds later he scales the lips on Z. I'm not sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: The only thing at 6:15 is extrution, then he just scale the lips on Z axis

Comment: exactly what he is doing... to scale the lips on z... he said he used RKEY? Nevertheless, I used SKEY and cannot replicate it! I just selected the front faces and side vertices but doesn't turn out like his model...

Comment: he uses Mays, not Blender, it may be different shortcuts. In Blender, to scale on Z, press S+Z

Comment: @moonboots ok, I tried that and somehow it it creates new surfaces. Is it possible to add an addition gif in this comment?

Comment: you should be able to edit your original question

Comment: @moonboots I edited it. I didn't see any relevant options for this command

Comment: so it seems like you scale like he does, except there's a problem with your topology, there is a hole but it's hard to understand what you've done and how it looks like, anyway you need to fix that. Also, if you are learning Blender, you should better follow Blender tutos rather than Maya  ;)

Comment: @moonboots it turned out my geometry was non-manifold. I checked via the 3d print toolbox. The scale comman works correctly. thanks for your support.